# Angular2 - Running all Unit Tests Fails Some Tests that Pass Individually

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit tests for my Angular project (Jasmine Karma).

All tests pass indidividually, but if I runn the whole suit, one test is failing with the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function thrown
```

Skipping the test before the failing test, and all tests are passing again. So I'm guessing I need to clean up after each or some tests.

Is this correct? And if so, how do I do the actuall cleaning of a test. I can't seem to find anything on this online.

**test before failing test**

```
    describe('CreateBindingComponent', () => {
      let component: CreateBindingComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreateBindingComponent>;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ CreateBindingComponent ],
          providers:[
            GetBindingEnumsService,
            GetBindingService,
            HttpClient,
            HttpHandler,
            CreateService,
          ],
          imports: [FormsModule, SelectDropDownModule, RouterTestingModule, MaterialModule]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateBindingComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

**failing test**

```
describe('DeleteDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: DeleteDialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DeleteDialogComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DeleteDialogComponent ],
      providers: [
        {provide : MatDialogRef, useValue : {}},
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {}},
        DeleteBindingService,
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler
      ],
      imports: [MaterialModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DeleteDialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I'm new to Angular so please let me know if I need to provide information or code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is your component code for CreateBindingComponent?

Comment: Also just some general observations.  These aren't really 'unit' tests as you're not mocking anything.  You're using all of your actual dependencies.  So these are setup as integration tests currently.  That's fine if that's what you intend but something to consider.  Also, if this is a large project or you're concerned about test run times I would discourage you from importing the entire material module and instead just import what's necessary for the component.  There will be a significant difference in run time between the two.  The setup is more annoying though so it is a trade off.

Comment: My company does not allow me to put code on stack. So unfortunately I cannot provide the component code.

Comment: I understood that TestBed automatically creates mocks from the providers you inject, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on importing only what is necessary. I'll check if i'm really using everything from the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Angular does not destroy listeners automatically to help you to get more details about your test execution. To remove it you simply use afterEach.

```
afterEach {
    fixture.destroy();
}
```

For More Details please check -> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18831

Comment: This is what worked for me, `afterEach(() => component.ngOnDestroy());`